# Google Analytics : Not getting day wise report is scheduled mail

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-firebase

I have created a custom report in GA with  metric group as Users and dimension as date.I sent this report in PDF format to my email id using "once" as frequency of the mail in "email report" window.

As expected ,in this report I get a chart where X axis represents dates and Y represents no of users on that date.

When I schedule this mail and use daily as frequency ,I get the email correctly ,but the dimension of the chart is shown as year and I no longer see dates across X axis.

So on X axis its as 2009 ,2010 and so on.Y axis is shown correct.

I am not sure why does this happen in case of scheduled reports only.I am using universal Analytics here.

Any inputs would be highly appreciated!thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is because on the daily report, only the data for the day that the email report is sent to you is included. If you look at the daily report, in the upper right corner, is the date range just one day? Unfortunately, there really isn't a "fix" for this issue, but there is a workaround which was mentioned in this Google forum, which you can try out:  https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/analytics/4iNe_6oeZ2c

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thnaks for reply.Yes.You are right.There is a range on top right corner.As suggested in the thread ,possible solution could be "schedule a report to be sent on the 1st, 8th, 15th, 22nd, and 29th (or 28th because of February) of every month" .If I go by this approach wouldn't I have to do this manually for each month,as some month may have 30days ,other many have 31 days etc. Is there any way I can schedule it one time and it would send report on 1st of each month with visits report of the previous month distributed datewise.

Comment: You would only need to change once for February, but if you schedule on days 1, 8, 15, 22, 29, this would cover all other months (as they have either 30/31 days). If you want to schedule on last day of month, then you would need to change more frequently. Not sure about the monthly report, but here's a document which may help: http://static.googleusercontent.com/media/www.google.com/en//grants/education/Google_Analytics_Scheduling_Reports.pdf. Would scheduling the report on the last day of month be an option? I haven't really played with scheduled reports, so sorry for my lack of knowledge!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it doesn't work as expected.
When I set up my reports, I had the same issue.
The "fix" as described in the in the google forum below doesn't exactly solve the issue either.

Shameless plug:
So I built my own at http://mysitevitals.com
It's a basic dashboard that pulls down your GA data and then uses Google Charts API to make 30 day rolling charts and then sends you the email every morning.